# unique elements in a haskell list

Tags: list, haskell

okay, this is probably going to be in the prelude, but: is there a standard library function for finding the unique elements in a list? my (re)implementation, for clarification, is:

```
has :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> Bool
has [] _ = False
has (x:xs) a
  | x == a    = True
  | otherwise = has xs a

unique :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
unique [] = []
unique (x:xs)
  | has xs x  = unique xs
  | otherwise = x : unique xs
```

Comment: Your `has` is also standard; it's just `flip elem`.

Comment: Or even `has xs = (\`elem\` xs)`.

Comment: @yatima2975 why are you using `elem` as infix?

Comment: @dopatraman Because `elem` has type `Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool` so using it as an infix operation section makes `xs` the second argument. ``(`elem` xs)`` is desugared to `(\x -> elem x xs)` which is what we want here!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The `nub` function from `Data.List` (no, it's actually not in the Prelude) definitely does something like what you want, but it is not quite the same as your `unique` function. They both preserve the original order of the elements, but `unique` retains the last
occurrence of each element, while `nub` retains the first occurrence.

You can do this to make `nub` act exactly like `unique`, if that's important (though I have a feeling it's not):

```
unique = reverse . nub . reverse
```

Also, `nub` is only good for small lists.
Its complexity is quadratic, so it starts to get slow if your list can contain hundreds of elements.

If you limit your types to types having an Ord instance, you can make it scale better.
This variation on `nub` still preserves the order of the list elements, but its complexity is `O(n * log n)`:

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set

nubOrd :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] 
nubOrd xs = go Set.empty xs where
  go s (x:xs)
   | x `Set.member` s = go s xs
   | otherwise        = x : go (Set.insert x s) xs
  go _ _              = []
```

In fact, it has been [proposed](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2717) to add `nubOrd` to `Data.Set`.

Comment: Arguably its best to simply leave it as a set instead of using a list in the first place

Comment: Let's be honest: `nub` isn't good for any list. Even on the list with 2 elements `nubOrd` is [faster](https://github.com/nh2/haskell-ordnub#dont-use-nub).

Comment: This is kind of like a "map sieve" similar to the impure "hash sieve".

Comment: There was a typo in a function type signature. Should be `Ord a`.
Also, I've found that nubOrd suprisingly (or not) isn't really better than nub in my case. It was even slower. Probably because there was not much duplicate values (though introducing nub cut running times in half, nub ord was about 20% slower than just nub).

Comment: @alternative, functions on lists can be more generally useful than the equivalent on sets by maintaining the order of items. This can be very important.

Answer (score 109):

I searched for `(Eq a) => [a] -> [a]` on [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/).

First result was [`nub`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Data-List.html#v:nub) (remove duplicate elements from a list).

Hoogle is awesome.

Comment: Also, you can provide you own equality function like this :

    nubBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]

Comment: And if Bart ever gets time we might see a nubOrd, which will be more reasonable performance wise.

Comment: It's worth saying that the `nub` function is from `Data.List` package.

Comment: @Thomas: Data.List.Unique has sortUniq, which is the "nubOrd" you're requesting.
I'd rather have a (Eq a, Hashable a) => [a] -> [a] which would be even more reasonable, performance-wise...

Comment: Up till now, I was really struggling to understand how to effectively use Hoogle, never thought of searching for the type signature I am looking for

Answer (score 14):

```
import Data.Set (toList, fromList)
uniquify lst = toList $ fromList lst
```

Comment: This changes the order of the elements.

Answer (score 4):

I think that unique should return a list of elements that only appear once in the original list; that is, any elements of the orginal list that appear more than once should not be included in the result.

May I suggest an alternative definition, unique_alt:

```
    unique_alt :: [Int] -> [Int]
    unique_alt [] = []
    unique_alt (x:xs)
        | elem x ( unique_alt xs ) = [ y | y <- ( unique_alt xs ), y /= x ]
        | otherwise                = x : ( unique_alt xs )
```

Here are some examples that highlight the differences between unique_alt and unqiue:

```
    unique     [1,2,1]          = [2,1]
    unique_alt [1,2,1]          = [2]

    unique     [1,2,1,2]        = [1,2]
    unique_alt [1,2,1,2]        = []

    unique     [4,2,1,3,2,3]    = [4,1,2,3]
    unique_alt [4,2,1,3,2,3]    = [4,1]
```

Comment: That is in fact the definition of Data.List.Unique (unique) although personally, I've never run unto that use case, whereas the "squash lists to contain only one of duplicates" function is bread-and-butter of many operations.

Answer (score 3):

I think this would do it.

```
unique [] = []
unique (x:xs) = x:unique (filter ((/=) x) xs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to remove duplicates:

```
unique :: [Int] -> [Int]
unique xs = [x | (x,y) <- zip xs [0..], x `notElem` (take y xs)]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Algorithm in Haskell to create a unique list:**

```
data Foo = Foo { id_ :: Int
               , name_ :: String
               } deriving (Show)

alldata = [ Foo 1 "Name"
          , Foo 2 "Name"
          , Foo 3 "Karl"
          , Foo 4 "Karl"
          , Foo 5 "Karl"
          , Foo 7 "Tim"
          , Foo 8 "Tim"
          , Foo 9 "Gaby"
          , Foo 9 "Name"
          ]

isolate :: [Foo] -> [Foo]
isolate [] = []
isolate (x:xs) = (fst f) : isolate (snd f)
  where
    f = foldl helper (x,[]) xs
    helper (a,b) y = if name_ x == name_ y
                     then if id_ x >= id_ y
                          then (x,b)
                          else (y,b)
                     else (a,y:b)

main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ (putStrLn . show) (isolate alldata)
```

**Output:**

```
Foo {id_ = 9, name_ = "Name"}
Foo {id_ = 9, name_ = "Gaby"}
Foo {id_ = 5, name_ = "Karl"}
Foo {id_ = 8, name_ = "Tim"}
```

Answer (score 0):

### A library-based solution:

We can use that style of Haskell programming where all looping and recursion activities are pushed out of user code and into suitable library functions. Said library functions are often optimized in ways that are way beyond the skills of a Haskell beginner.

A way to decompose the problem into two passes goes like this:

1. produce a second list that is *parallel* to the input list, but with duplicate elements suitably marked
2. eliminate elements marked as duplicates from that second list

For the first step, duplicate elements don't need a value at all, so we can use `[Maybe a]` as the type of the second list. So we need a function of type:

```
pass1 :: Eq a => [a] -> [Maybe a]
```

Function `pass1` is an example of *stateful list traversal* where the *state* is the list (or set) of distinct elements seen so far. For this sort of problem, the library provides the [`mapAccumL :: (s -> a -> (s, b)) -> s -> [a] -> (s, [b])`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:mapAccumL) function.

Here the `mapAccumL` function requires, besides the initial state and the input list, a *step function* argument, of type `s -> a -> (s, Maybe a)`.

If the current element `x` is not a duplicate, the output of the step function is `Just x` and `x` gets added to the current state. If x is a duplicate, the output of the step function is `Nothing`, and the state is passed unchanged.

Testing under the `ghci` interpreter:

```
$ ghci
 GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 λ> 
 λ> stepFn s x = if (elem x s) then (s, Nothing) else (x:s, Just x)
 λ> 
 λ> import Data.List(mapAccumL)
 λ> 
 λ> pass1 xs = mapAccumL stepFn [] xs
 λ> 
 λ> xs2 = snd $ pass1 "abacrba"
 λ> xs2
 [Just 'a', Just 'b', Nothing, Just 'c', Just 'r', Nothing, Nothing]
 λ>
```

Writing a `pass2` function is even easier. To filter out `Nothing` non-values, we could use:

```
import Data.Maybe( fromJust, isJust)
pass2 = (map fromJust) . (filter isJust)
```

but why bother at all ? - as this is precisely what the `catMaybes` library function does.

```
 λ> 
 λ> import Data.Maybe(catMaybes)
 λ> 
 λ> catMaybes xs2
 "abcr"
 λ>
```

### Putting it all together:

Overall, the source code can be written as:

```
import Data.Maybe(catMaybes)
import Data.List(mapAccumL)

uniques :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
uniques = let  stepFn s x = if (elem x s) then (s, Nothing) else (x:s, Just x)
          in   catMaybes . snd . mapAccumL stepFn []
```

This code is reasonably compatible with infinite lists, something occasionally referred to as being “laziness-friendly”:

```
 λ> 
 λ> take 5 $ uniques $ "abacrba" ++ (cycle "abcrf")
 "abcrf"
 λ>
```

**Efficiency note:**
If we anticipate that it is possible to find many distinct elements in the input list and we can have an `Ord a` instance, the *state* can be implemented as a `Set` object rather than a plain list, this without having to alter the overall structure of the solution.