# How can I write a parser using Parsec that only accepts unique elements?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, parsec

I have recently started learning Haskell and have been trying my hand at Parsec. However, for the past couple of days I have been stuck with a problem that I have been unable to find the solution to. So what I am trying to do is write a parser that can parse a string like this:

```
<"apple", "pear", "pineapple", "orange">
```

The code that I wrote to do that is:

```
collection :: Parser [String]    
collection = (char '<') *> (string `sepBy` char ',')) <* (char '>')

string :: Parser String
string = char '"' *> (many (noneOf ['\"', '\r', '\n', '"'])) <* char '"'
```

This works fine for me as it is able to parse the string that I have defined above. Nevertheless, I would now like to enforce the rule that every element in this collection must be unique and that is where I am having trouble. One of the first results I found when searching on the internet was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098391/unique-elements-in-a-haskell-list) one, which suggest the usage of the `nub` function. Although the problem stated in that question is not the same, it would in theory solve my problem. But what I don't understand is how I can apply this function within a Parser. I have tried adding the nub function to several parts of the code above without any success. Later I also tried doing it the following way:

```
 collection :: Parser [String]
 collection = do
  char '<'
  value <- (string `sepBy` char ','))
  char '>'
  return nub value
```

But this does not work as the type does not match what `nub` is expecting, which I believe is one of the problems I am struggling with. I am also not entirely sure whether `nub` is the right way to go. My fear is that I am going in the wrong direction and that I won't be able to solve my problem like this. Is there perhaps something I am missing? Any advice or help anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `return $ nub value` - this is a simple typographical error. Right now you're trying to apply `return` to `nub`, instead of to `nub value`. Note that this will _not_ make your parser only parse a unique list of items, it will merely filter out duplicates that exist in the list.

Comment: @Cubic Thank you for pointing this out, this indeed works and you are right in that this will not make my parser parse a unique list of items, but it is already pretty close to what I want to achieve. What I am wondering is whether what I want to achieve is possible using a parser or whether I should perhaps try to achieve this in another way.

Comment: Spoilers: yes, it's possible - but if you don't restrict the possible strings in that list you're entering context sensitive territory. You have to parse the list in a more manual way though, because you'll need to remember list items you've already looked at.

Comment: It should be possible but I think this *requires* the monadic interface. Using only `Applicative` I don't think this is achievable.

Comment: @Cubic, it would be possible to parse the list as in the current code, but then to `=<<` on a function checking that elements are unique. The downside is that failure won't be detected till the list is completely parsed, but the code will be simple.

Comment: You can use `do ... value <- ... ; guard (noDuplicates value); return value`, after having defined your own custom predicate `noDuplicates :: [String] -> Bool`. Note that this will make the parser fail only after the whole list is parsed -- you may want to fail as soon as the first duplicate is found instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Parsec `Parser` type is an instance of `MonadPlus` which means that we can always fail (ie cause a parse error) whenever we want. A handy function for this is `guard`:

```
guard :: MonadPlus m => Bool -> m ()
```

This function takes a boolean. If it's true, it return `()` and the whole computation (a parse in this case) does not fail. If it's false, the whole thing fails.

So, as long as you don't care about efficiency, here's a reasonable approach: parse the whole list, check for whether all the elements are unique and fail if they aren't.

To do this, the first thing we have to do is write a predicate that checks if every element of a list is unique. `nub` does not quite do the right thing: it return a list with all the duplicates taken out. But if we don't care much about performance, we can use it to check:

```
allUnique ls = length (nub ls) == length ls
```

With this predicate in hand, we can write a function `unique` that wraps *any* parser that produces a list and ensures that list is unique:

```
unique parser = do res <- parser
                   guard (allUnique res)
                   return res
```

Again, if `guard` is give `True`, it doesn't affect the rest of the parse. But if it's given `False`, it will cause an error.

Here's how we could use it:

```
λ> parse (unique collection) "<interactive>" "<\"apple\",\"pear\",\"pineapple\",\"orange\">"
Right ["apple","pear","pineapple","orange"]
λ> parse (unique collection) "<interactive>" "<\"apple\",\"pear\",\"pineapple\",\"orange\",\"apple\">"
Left "<interactive>" (line 1, column 46):unknown parse error
```

This does what you want. However, there's a problem: there is no error message supplied. That's not very user friendly! Happily, we can fix this using `<?>`. This is an operator provided by Parsec that lets us set the error message of a parser.

```
unique parser = do res <- parser
                   guard (allUnique res) <?> "unique elements"
                   return res
```

Ahhh, much better:

```
λ> parse (unique collection) "<interactive>" "<\"apple\",\"pear\",\"pineapple\",\"orange\",\"apple\">"
Left "<interactive>" (line 1, column 46):
expecting unique elements
```

All this works but, again, it's worth noting that it isn't efficient. It parses the whole list before realizing elements aren't unique, and `nub` takes quadratic time. However, this works and it's probably more than good enough for parsing small to medium-sized files: ie most things written by hand rather than autogenerated.

Comment: To improve efficiency redefine `allUnique ls = size (fromList ls) == length ls` where you `import Data.Set(size, fromList)`. This should take O(nlogn) (which is optimal). It changes the constraint from `Eq` to `Ord` but this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: With the Functor-Applicative-Monad proposal in effect, `guard` now has type `Alternative f => Bool -> f ()`, but that's fine because Parsec parsers also have an `Alternative` instance.

Comment: `guard` gives the 'expecting ...' error message; this isn't always appropriate and then you can use `when cond $ fail "message here"` to get an error message that is not 'expecting'.