# Words without reccurence in haskell

Tags: string, haskell, io, unique-index

I wonder one thing in haskell while i was working around lists of strings. For example when i try to something like;

```
words "hello world"
```

It sends the words into an array and whenever i want to get an element i use "!!" notation as normal. 
Given us a text, how can we find the words such that they have no other from itself? For example in "hello world" case both "hello" and "world" are unique words but if i write "hello hello world" in this case only the world is unique. How can i implement such code? Will using words still be useful? Is there a default method for that reason?

Comment: quibble: words creates a *list* not an array. Also, you might want to look at [`nub`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=nub) or [`Data.Set.fromList`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Data.Set.fromList)

Comment: Well it behaves like one :) i don't want to miss duplicates of one word. I wonder if there are, how can i delete them and leave the unique ones alone?

Comment: You can look at the two reference @rampion provided and the one I provided: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098391/unique-elements-in-a-haskell-list#3098417

Comment: Ohh i double searched but couldn't see the duplicate question. So sorry. Thanks for help guys!

Comment: Here's how they differ: a list in haskell has takes 1 step to prepend a new element, but `n` steps to access the `n`'th element. An array can access it's `n`'th element in a single step, but prepending an element can take a number of steps equal to the size of the array.