# Prevent repeat printing of common list variables Haskell

Tags: haskell

Currently, I am making a function that can take the values in two lists, compare them, and print any similar values. If a value is duplicated in both lists, it is not printed a second time.

```
EXAMPLE

INPUT: commons [1,2,2,3,4] [2,3,4,5,2,6,8]
EXPECTED OUTPUT: [2,3,4]
```

What I currently have causes a repeated values in both lists to repeat in the output. So, in the above example, the 2 would print twice.

Here is the current code I am working on:

```
commons :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
commons [] [] = []
commons x y = commons_Helper x y

commons_Helper :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
commons_Helper [] [] = []
commons_Helper x [] = []
commons_Helper [] y = []
commons_Helper (x:xs) y = 
    if elem x y then x : commons_Helper xs y
    else commons_Helper xs y
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This must remain as commons :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a], and I cannot import and libraries

Comment: You could try to operate in two steps. Step 1 being just your `commons_Helper` function. And step 2 just needs to eliminate duplicates from a single list. For step 2, you can look at that [earlier SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098391/unique-elements-in-a-haskell-list)

Comment: Have you considered using [`Set`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.5.1/docs/Data-Set.html)s instead of lists?

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I am unfortunatley not able in import any libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your traversal of the `xs` list a *stateful* one, the *state* keeping track of elements that have been already seen. The state begins life as an empty list.

It is possible to do that by adding a 3rd parameter to your helper function, which currently is not very useful.

```
commons_Helper :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
commons_Helper   []    ys  st  =  []
commons_Helper (x:xs)  ys  st  = 
    if (elem x ys  &&  (not $ elem x st))     -- extra test here
        then  x : (commons_Helper xs ys (x:st))
        else  commons_Helper xs ys st


commons :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
commons xs ys = commons_Helper xs ys []
```

This state-based technique is very common in Haskell. There is even a library function:  [`mapAccumL :: (s -> a -> (s, b)) -> s -> [a] -> (s, [b])`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:mapAccumL) to support it.

Comment: I forgot to put it in the original question (fixed now) but this need sot remain


commons :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]

Comment: @D.Hardie And you'll notice that the suggested answer still has `commons :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]`. `commons` **uses** `commons_Helper` internally, and `commons_Helper` has a different type, but that doesn't affect the type that `commons` itself has. (Indeed needing to use something internally that has a different interface is almost entirely the point of using a helper function at all)

Comment: I understand that quite often in the library source code, the *helper function* is known as `go`, like [here for foldr1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#foldr1) for example. But when answering a SO question, we try to stick to the OP's vocabulary.

Comment: Using a neutral word such as `go` for the helper function has the following benefit: when in the course of software development, we decide to change the name of the user-visible function, `go` can just remain `go`. While if the function is naïvely recursive, a simple change of name for the function takes several changes in the source code, and that's error prone.